# "Nilpotency" of an Element

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am not sure if such a concept has really been treated in depth, but while working on a problem I came up with this idea of the "nilpotency" of an element in a ring, analogous to the order of an element. I did search google a bit, but I didn't find much. Specifically, if $x$ is a nilpotent element in the ring $R$, then its nilpotency is the smallest natural number $n$ for which $x^n =0$. We know such a concept is well-defined, because $x$ is indeed nilpotent, then the well-ordering property guarantees a smallest natural number.

This question arose in connection to the following scenario:

> If $R$ is a commutative ring and $x$ and $y$ are nilpotent elements, will the nilpotency of the product $xy$ be the least common multiple of $x$ and $y$'s nilpotency?

Letting $\ell$ denote this least common multiple, it isn't difficult to show $(xy)^\ell = 0$, but I was having trouble showing this is the smallest natural number. I am probably overlooking something very simple. Does anyone know if this is even true?

Comment: No, it will in general be much smaller than that. For one thing, the nilpotency of either element is an upper bound, and there is no reason it could not just be $1$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Nop. For example, in $\;R:=\Bbb Z/36\Bbb Z\;$ , the elements $\;6,\,12\;$ have both nilpotency order of $\;2\;$ , yet their product is $\;6\cdot12=72=0\;$